# migration from JBoss 4.X to 7.1 Issue

Tags: ejb, jndi, jboss7.x

I am migrating application from JBOSS 4.X to JBoss 7.1. I am facing one problem as metioned here

```
myApp.ear
     + ---- lib
     |       |------- common.jar
     |
    +----- META-INF
    |       +-- jboss-deployment-structure.xml and  other config files
    |       
    |
    | ---- xxxEJB.jar
    + ---- xxxWebApp.war

jboss-deployment-structure.xml in ear/meta-inf is as follows
<jboss-deployment-structure> 
<ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javaee.api" export="true"/>//module.xml
        <module name="sun.jdk" export="true"/>
        <module name="com.lib" export="true"/>
        <module name="deployment.myapp.ear.xxxejb.jar"/>
    </dependencies>
</deployment>   
<sub-deployment name="xxxwebapp.war">
    <resources>
         <resource-root path="common.jar" >
         </resource-root>
    </resources>
</sub-deployment>

</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I am getting the following exception when trying to invoke the application

```
08:05:06,546 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.xxx.session.UserMgrHome -- service jboss.naming.context.java."com.xxx.session.UserMgrHome"

08:05:06,546 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:97)

08:05:06,546 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:178)

08:05:06,546 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:113)

08:05:06,546 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:214)

08:05:06,562 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
```

Any pointers to this Please

Thanks and regards
Srini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used java:global/earName/ejbjarName/ejbName!com.xxx.ejbNameSessionHome and working fine

Answer (score 3):

I note this:

```
<module name="deployment.myapp.ear.xxxejb.jar"/>
```

The correct for nothing problems is:

```
<module name="deployment.myapp.ear.xxxEJB.jar"/>
```

remember that this **case sensitive** !

Answer (score 1):

With such a short stack trace it's hard to tell the problem. It looks as if your JNDI look up fails. Check out the new [JNDI namespace names](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+AS5+or+AS6+to+AS7#HowdoImigratemyapplicationfromAS5orAS6toAS7-UpdateapplicationJNDInamespacenames) in AS7.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss Create JNDI Name every time.

**Example:**

jndi-name="java:global/demo-ear/demo-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/TestService!com.TestService"

and follow this link

[JBoss 7.1 development issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897339/jboss-7-1-development-issues/21107215#21107215)