# JBoss 7.1 development issues

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss6.x

I am new to JBoss 7.1 and trying to migrate our appplication to migrate from jboss 6.0 to jboss 7.1 but at development time it loads only few specific jars automatically which is different from jboss 6.0 which loads all the jars from lib folder.If i add them externally then at deployement time it conflicts with the already available jars in jboss 7.1 /module folder.

so please let me know how to configure the jboss 7.1 so that it loads all or specified its internal jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use your own jar for the deployed application, then you can exclude these using a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file in your WEB-INF directory. Here is [an example](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/Exclude_a_Subsystem_from_a_Deployment.html) that describes about the format of the xml file.

Comment: well thanks for your reply but the thing is that Jboss 7.1 includes only some specific jars like hibernate-net.jar,commons.jar etc but not all of the jar files available in jboss7.1 at development time not all of the jars as in case of jboss6.0

Answer (score 0):

I too faced same issue. One best thing I did was removing conflicting jars in JBoss lib folder as your deployment ear would have those already.

Answer (score 0):

**JBoss As 7.1 & JSF1.2, 2.0**

---

Following required steps...

You have manually configure some files

1.Create folder MySQL folder\main folder
jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules\com\mysql

2.MySQL folder\module folder\add-> module.xml file and MySQL connector file

```
    Module.xml code:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql">
       <resources>
            <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.10-bin.jar"/>
            <!-- Insert resources here -->
        </resources>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javax.api"/>
            <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
            <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
        </dependencies>
    </module>
```

```
3.Go to the JBoss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules\org\hibernate\main
open the module.xml file & add
<module name="com.mysql"/>
```

```
4.Go to the JBoss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules\org\jboss\as\weld\main
open the module.xml file & add
 <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="1.2"/>
```

```
5.Go to the JBoss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules\org\jboss\weld\core\main
open the module.xml file & add
<module name="javax.faces.api" slot="1.2"/>
```